# clear cache inside tinymce editor

Tags: php, caching, http-headers, tinymce

I have a page that uses tinymce editor, the editor will retrieve a template when i need it to, though the template can be changed i.e images can be modified, now the problem is that whenever i change the images of the template "this is done from a different page", it does not reflect on the tinymce editor when i open the same template, i tried this methods for clearing the cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

also

```
clearstatcache();
```

and

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

but to no avail, i'm guessing the problem lies within the tinymce editor. is there anyway for me to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a query string parameter 'cache busting' technique.

If you append `?v=xxx` to the URL targeting `tiny_mce.js` TinyMCE will append that same query string value to all the URLs it requests. :)

e.g.

```
/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js?cachebuster=123
```

or (if using jQuery)

```
$('#elementId').tinymce({"script_url":"/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js?cachebuster=123", ...);
```

You then just need to modify the query string cache buster value whenever you make modifications to any of the files TinyMCE is calling.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this in the head where the script is included, that forces tinyMCE to reload without cache... it works for me.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../tiny/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js?<?php        echo(rand(1,10));?>"></script>
</head>
```